Create different forked diffraction gratings from equations using geometry nodes for 3d printing
I'm trying to create different forked diffraction gratings from equations using geometry nodes for 3D printing
Forked diffraction grating pattern equation
$$T(x,y) = P_e \left(\frac{2\pi}{d} x - p\theta\right)$$
Some theory: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-25779-x
See example of image below of what the equation should create.

I'm having some trouble converting the equations to work with geometry nodes.
My planned steps:

Create curves from equation.
Apply mesh to curve to give it depth for 3D printing.

It's based off of this video How To Make a Spiral Out of Light
https://youtu.be/dDwaZ-q3DIk
I looked at Solving mathematical XYZ equations in geometry nodes?  but the equation format is a little different.
So I tried applying this format https://youtu.be/3Z_as4UEJLA to see if it would work.  (I had issues with that to)
I tried using chatgpt to place it into a format that blender would understand but it gave me extra terms which didn't make sense to me.
What I have:

Equation:

see attached blend file below

Note: I did think of drawing it but I want to make it procedural so I can test different numerical parameters.
2nd note: The total size when this is 3D printed out to test a laser with is 5mm X 5mm with a height of 2mm

Shouldn't this be a shader ? the same nodes could be used to displace in GN, if that's what you mean..

@RobinBetts the issue I've run into is converting shader nodes into
clean" geometry that can be 3d printed correctly.   The Mesh doesn't come out as "clean" as using an equation, curves, and a curve to mesh node directly in geometry nodes but if you know of a way I'm certainly willing to give it a try.

I think a description of the intended clean finished product would help, here? .. I know we're not printers, but some idea of the constraints on the model, scale, etc, might help us to reject unacceptable suggestions.

@RobinBetts Sure, the total size when this is 3D printed out to test with a laser is 5mm X 5mm with a 2mm height (very small)

Since you want this as geometry, you must transform the equation into a boolean and make a selection.
The input geometry must be a well subdivided plane:
(making this as curves is very tricky, the equation does not describe lines, it describes "intensities")

The equation was literally copied from the site, where:

There was a transformation to polar angle
I exchanged X with Y probably because the angle reference in the article was not standard
Had to make a boolean to filter selected geometry


File:


Thanks! this really helps.
